# Conditional builds for crates in workspace

Tags: rust-cargo

nub here. Let's say I have the workspace

```
bar-win-x86-x64_nightly v0.1.0 
└── rand v0.8.5
    ├── rand_chacha v0.3.1
    │   ├── ppv-lite86 v0.2.17
    │   └── rand_core v0.6.4
    │       └── getrandom v0.2.9
    │           └── cfg-if v1.0.0
    └── rand_core v0.6.4 (*)

baz-win-x86 v0.1.0
├── bar-win-x86-x64_nightly v0.1.0 (*)
└── rand v0.8.5 (*)

foo-xxx v0.1.0

qux-win-x64 v0.1.0
├── bar-win-x86-x64_nightly v0.1.0 (*)
└── foo-xxx v0.1.0

wasm-unknw v0.1.0
└── foo-xxx v0.1.0
```

and I want to get:

```
cargo build --target="i686-pc-windows-msvc"
```

foo-xxx (stable) + baz-win-x86 (stable) + bar-win-x86-x64_nightly (nightly)
and nothing else. Is it possible for stable crate to depend on nightly one?

```
cargo build --target="wasm32-unknown-unknown"
```

foo-xxx (stable) + wasm-unknw (stable)
and nothing else

```
cargo build --target="x86_64-apple-darwin"
```

foo-xxx (stable)

etc.

What should I do ? I've tried `.cargo/config.toml and rust-toolchain.toml` with no success.  It's looks like cargo ignores the rules for crates in workspace.

Comment: Did you ever figure it out?